# Achieving exactly the same box shadow all around a button

Tags: html, css

I have a box shadow on top which I want to have all the way around a button. How do I do this?

```css
.btn.btn-filled {
  color: white !important;
  padding: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0px -5px 5px -5px #808080;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="btn btn-lg btn-filled" href="https://adsler.co.uk">Design</a>
  <a class="btn btn-lg btn-white" href="http://4309.co.uk/portraits/">Illustration</a>
</div>
```

[view here](http:///4309.co.uk)

Comment: Also check out: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/
The 4 values are horizontal offset, vertical offset, blur radius and spread radius. You'll want to set both offsets to 0px and then play around with blur radius and spread radius (spread can also be negative, e.g. -5px)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
button{
    background: #000000 !important;
    border: 2px solid #000000 !important;
    color:white;
    border-radius:50px;
    padding:10px 30px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #808080;
    }
```

```html
<button>
Design</button>
```

this what you are looking for :

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px #808080;
```

Comment: Thanks. But with your code, won't the shadow density be slightly different to what I have at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

@New, this is very simple. If you use **box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #000;** this way then you will get around the shadow of button.

Thanks.

Comment: Will that be exactly the same box shadow  density all the way around as I have at the moment?

Comment: @New if you change 4th child of number then your box-shadow size will be change.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
}

.btn.btn-filled {
  color: white !important;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.9);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.9);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="btn btn-lg btn-filled" href="https://adsler.co.uk">Design</a>
  <a class="btn btn-lg btn-white" href="http://4309.co.uk/portraits/">Illustration</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!Doctype>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .allblur
    {
        width:350px;height:200px;
        border: solid 1px #555;
        background-color: #eed;
        box-shadow:  0 0 10px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px  5px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        -o-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="allblur">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```